# How to ensure flexbox is smaller than surrounding elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to implement a Flexbox container for an image gallery. I would like this gallery to not require the use of a scrollbar and instead adjust the size of the images to fit the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 90%;
}

.img-wrap {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.img-wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text-wrap">This should always be visible</div>

<div id="flex-container">

    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/800"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250"></div>

    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/450/505"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/350/520"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/300"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/200"></div>

    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/800"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250"></div>

    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/450/505"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/350/520"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/300"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/550/200"></div>

</div>

<div class="text-wrap">This should always be visible, even without using a scrollbar</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the window is small enough (vertically), the bottom text gets cut off and the user needs to scroll to see it.

I would like to have both sections of text always visible. The images should always get smaller until both sections of text are touching, at which point a scrollbar is acceptable.

Comment: How about a sticky header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

Add position fixed on text-wrap class, it will fix the position of top and bottom heading.

```
.text-wrap {
    postion:fixed;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Have you tried entering this yourself?

Comment: Yeah I have tried. But you asked for position so I have not focussed anything else. There have a problem with top heading. I am not on PC now so I can't fix it now. But edit your question with entire project I will fix it for you tomorrow.